# Neo4j - Speeding up a query with optional matches and collects (slow)

Tags: database, search, graph, neo4j, cypher

Does anyone have any ideas on how to speed this up? The optional matches are slowing down the query, but I don't know another way to achieve the same thing.

I'm exporting all the user data to Elasticsearch, so it can be searchable.

```
MATCH (u:User {id: [ID-HERE]})
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:FOLLOWS]->(u1)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:HAS_PROFESSION]->(p)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:HAS_SKILL]->(s)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:HAS_INDUSTRY]->(i)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:HAS_EXPERIENCE]->(e)
RETURN
u.id AS id,
u.firstName AS firstName,
u.lastName AS lastName,
u.createdAt AS createdAt,
collect(DISTINCT u1.id) AS usersFollowing,
collect(DISTINCT p.id) AS professionIds,
collect(DISTINCT p.name) AS professions,
collect(DISTINCT s.id) AS skillIds,
collect(DISTINCT s.name) AS skills,
collect(DISTINCT i.name) AS industries,
collect(DISTINCT e.name) AS experiences


Indexes
   ON :Industry(id) ONLINE  (for uniqueness constraint)
   ON :Page(name) ONLINE  (for uniqueness constraint)
   ON :Profession(id) ONLINE  (for uniqueness constraint)
   ON :Skill(id) ONLINE  (for uniqueness constraint)
   ON :User(id) ONLINE  (for uniqueness constraint)

Constraints
   ON ( industry:Industry ) ASSERT industry.id IS UNIQUE
   ON ( page:Page ) ASSERT page.name IS UNIQUE
   ON ( profession:Profession ) ASSERT profession.id IS UNIQUE
   ON ( skill:Skill ) ASSERT skill.id IS UNIQUE
   ON ( user:User ) ASSERT user.id IS UNIQUE
```

[image]

Query explain:
[image]

Query profile:
[image]

Comment: Please, share more details about your problem. For example: your data model and what goal are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, have you added an index in the id property of :User nodes?

Comment: You can add an index this way: `CREATE INDEX ON :Person(firstname)`. Note that an index is not immediately available, but will be created in the background.

Comment: @BrunoPeres updated with more info. Basically exporting all the data from Neo to Elasticsearch

Comment: You can try changing the optional match by a variable length path *0..1. This will turn the path optional too. Remove all your matches and add only this and try: `MATCH (u:User {id: [ID-HERE]}),
(u)-[:FOLLOWS*0..1]->(u1),
(u)-[:HAS_PROFESSION*0..1]->(p),
(u)-[:HAS_SKILL*0..1]->(s),
(u)-[:HAS_INDUSTRY*0..1]->(i),
(u)-[:HAS_EXPERIENCE*0..1]->(e)`

Comment: Can you give the `EXPLAIN` of your query ?

Comment: Are `DISTINCT` really required ?

Comment: @logisima yes distinct was required. Added explain and profile images

Comment: @BrunoPeres that performs slower

Comment: @logisima without DISTINCT in each of those, the query takes too long and crashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this query will be better, but you can test it :

```
MATCH (u:User {id: [ID-HERE]})
RETURN
u.id AS id,
u.firstName AS firstName,
u.lastName AS lastName,
u.createdAt AS createdAt,
[(u)-[:FOLLOWS]->(u1) | u1.id] AS  usersFollowing,
[(u)-[:HAS_PROFESSION]->(p) | p.id] AS professionIds,
[(u)-[:HAS_SKILL]->(s) | s.id] AS skillsId,
[(u)-[:HAS_INDUSTRY]->(i) | i.name] AS industries,
[(u)-[:HAS_EXPERIENCE]->(e) | e.name] AS experiences
```

Comment: WOW! How does that work? It seems like a 1000+ times faster (when running one query). Need to verify the data the is correct.

Comment: I used: MATCH (u:User {id: ${id}})
            RETURN
              u,
              [(u)-[:FOLLOWS]->(u1) | u1.id] AS usersFollowing,
              [(u)-[:HAS_PROFESSION]->(p) | p.id] AS professionIds,
              [(u)-[:HAS_PROFESSION]->(p) | p.name] AS professions,
              [(u)-[:HAS_SKILL]->(s) | s.id] AS skillsId,
              [(u)-[:HAS_SKILL]->(s) | s.name] AS skills,
              [(u)-[:HAS_INDUSTRY]->(i) | i.name] AS industries,
              [(u)-[:HAS_EXPERIENCE]->(e) | e.name] AS experiences

Comment: It also seems that using the entire u object, rather than aliasing each field is quicker too. (There are more fields being used than shown)

Comment: Is there any way to make the fields unique? (e.g. [(u)-[:HAS_PROJECT]->()-[:PROJECT_HAS_INDUSTRY]->(s) | s.name] AS projectIndustries)

Answer (score 2):

You can get a similar result to logisima's query by collecting immediately after each OPTIONAL MATCH.

The reason for the performance issues you're seeing in your query is that in Cypher, rows are built up for all possible results as the query progresses. In the case of your OPTIONAL MATCHes, your results are being multiplied because of cross products with the results of those matches, and subsequent operations execute per-row, so you're performing more and more extra unnecessary work each time.

So you start off with a single row with `u`. Cardinality is 1.

After your first OPTIONAL MATCH, you have 3 rows, one for each result, all with the same `u`.

The next OPTIONAL MATCH executes for each of those 3 rows. 3 results are found, so you get 9 rows (your previous 3 results in combination with the 3 new results), all with the same `u`.

The next OPTIONAL MATCH executes for each of those 9 rows. No additional results are found, the rows remain at 9.

The next OPTIONAL MATCH executes for each of those 9 rows. 10 results are found. Those in combination with your previous 9 rows equals 90 rows. Again, all with the same `u`.

The next OPTIONAL MATCH executes for each of those 90 rows. 266 results are found. Those in combination with your previous 90 rows equals 23940 rows.

Then you have to do property access. Even though you have a single `u` in common for all rows, property access happens across all rows (so you're doing 23940 times the work doing property access on the same single node redundantly), then the distinct operations for each of the collections so you don't get the duplicates that resulted from the cross product of all your optional match results (otherwise, without distinct, you would get a single row and each collection would be 23940 elements long, with many many duplicate elements).

To keep the cardinality under control for the query, you either have to collect results immediately after each OPTIONAL MATCH (this applies when you're doing MATCHes too and need to collect the results), which will keep the cardinality down to a single row after each collect(), or you can use pattern comprehension as in logisima's query, since each comprehension executes the match on the single row and immediately collects it.

The lesson here is mind the cardinality of your query, aggregate early if possible to keep your rows down, because your subsequent query operations execute multiplicatively on the rows you're building up as the query progresses.

Comment: Thank you very much for that insight!